# Stop Apache Decoding URL Components

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I don't know if the title says it or not, but basically, I am using .htaccess to pass on an entire URL to my PHP file using a URL.

Example: http://example.com/var1/var2/http://example.net/logo.png/image.png

In this case, logo.png would be put inside image.png by my code.

I have tried Javascript to encode the variable URL.

http://example.org/utilities/banner-generator/Testyz/Testy/http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.example.com%2Ffiles%2Favatar%2F1498768_1.png/banner.png

This is what the URL looks like but Apache still treats the encoded slashes as normal slashes.

Is it possible to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Could you provide the rules you're using ? A wild guess would be to use the [`NE flag`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne)

Comment: @HamZa `RewriteRule ^utilities/banner-generator/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/banner.png$ /include/image/banner.php?name=$1&description=$2&icon=$3 [NE,L,NC,QSA]
`

Comment: Just found out that the web server doesn't like the % sign.

Comment: Oh I see ... I would suggest to replace the last `([^/]*)` with `(.*?)`

Comment: Yeah, I did that. It's now saying Bad Request when I use % :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick is to use `B` flag with `THE_REQUEST` in condition.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+utilities/banner-generator/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+?)/banner\.png [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /include/image/banner.php?name=%1&description=%2&icon=%3 [NE,B,L,QSA]
```